# TreeView binding to List<Itemes>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I have a list of items, where each item in the list contains another list of items.

```
public List<JobesGroup> JobeGroups { get; set; } = new List<JobesGroup>() 
{
   new JobesGroup()
   {
       ID=1,
       GroupName="test1",
       Jobes=new List<Jobe>()
       {
           new Jobe()
           {
               ID=1,
               JobeName="sss"
           },
           new Jobe()
           {
               ID=2,
               JobeName="aaa"
           }
       }
   },
   new JobesGroup()
   {
       ID=2,
       GroupName="test2",
       Jobes=new List<Jobe>()
       {
           new Jobe()
           {
               ID=3,
               JobeName="ddd"
           },
           new Jobe()
           {
               ID=4,
               JobeName="fff"
           }
       }
   }
};
```

I want the `TreeView` main items to show the `GroupName` and the subitemes wo show the `JobName`. How to bind it to the `TreeView`?

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there. What have you tried and where do you get stucked?

Comment: i tried over 10 videos and 6 tutorial nothing show or some times crash

Comment: So you ask here for the 7th tutorial which may also show nothing or crash? It is very obvious that you do something basic wrong. But without knowing that, we can not help you. Please add the code what you have tried and tell us what goes wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a hierarchical data structure, meaning an item contains another collection of items. A [`TreeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.DataTemplate);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) can display hierarchical data using [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0)s. Such a template defines the apprearance of an item and specifies the [`ItemsSource`](https://ItemsSource) for the next level. It can also define a data template for the next level explicitly by using the [`ItemTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.itemtemplate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property. This can either be a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) or a [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.DataTemplate);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) depending on the level providing hierarchical or non-hierarchical data. If no other item template is specified, the same data template will be applied to all items across all levels.

The first level are `JobesGroup` items and the second level are `Jobes` items.

- First level: Needs an `HierarchicalDataTemplate` that defines how `GroupName` is shown and specifies the `Jobes` property as the `ItemsSource` of the next level.
- Second level: A simple `DataTemplate` for `JobeName` is enough, since there are no more levels underneath. It defines how `JobeName` is displayed.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding JobeGroups}">
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:JobesGroup}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Jobes}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Jobe}">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding JobeName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```